# UiImageView + AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, imageview, afnetworking

У меня есть меню боковое(таблица) в ней картинка в Headers находится, грузится она с сервера по ссылке методом:

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = headerCell.imageViewPhoto;

NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://11.111.111.1/%@",[[LZSettingsManager instance] objForKey:kUserPhotoUrl]]]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:60];

[headerCell.imageViewPhoto setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuEmptyUserPhoto"] success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {

    weakImageView.alpha = 0.0;
    weakImageView.image = image;
   //  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTableMenu" object:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         weakImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }];

} failure:NULL];
```

При первом запуске все супер грузится. Далее я лезу в профиль меняю картинку и все хорошо на сервере она меняется, но ссылка остается на нее та же. (например быа www.image1.png и стала www.image1.png) так вот после смены картинки я обновляю таблицу методом

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Но картинка остается та же! она не меняется, уже и с кешем пробовал и делал `self.imageViewPhoto.image = nil;` все равно не меняется, выходишь из приложения и снова заходишь, все картинка новая.
Как сделать чтобы сразу грузилась новая по той же ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Кэш в AFNetworking не отключаемый.
Чтобы не менять основную библиотеку, сделайте category. Например

`UIImageView (clearCache)`

со следующими методами:

```
- (void)clearImageCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    UIImage *cachedImage = [[[self class] sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:request];
    if (cachedImage) {
        [self clearCached:[[self class] sharedImageCache] Request:request];
    }
}

- (void)clearCached:(NSCache *)imageCache Request:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if (request) {
        [imageCache removeObjectForKey:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
    }
}
```

Вызовом `clearImageCacheForURL` сможете чистить предыдущее изображение в кэше.

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить только закомментировав код в файле `UIImageView+AFNetworking.m`

```
//    //Use the image from the image cache if it exists
//    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageforRequest:urlRequest withAdditionalIdentifier:nil];
//    if (cachedImage) {
//        if (success) {
//            success(urlRequest, nil, cachedImage);
//        } else {
//            self.image = cachedImage;
//        }
//        [self clearActiveDownloadInformation];
//    } else {
```